# Lambdaj Error on Android

Tags: android, lambdaj

I am tryng to use [lambdaj 2.4](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) with dependencies in my android application. However when I try to use following select statement:

```
List<MOExpectedIncidentData> list = select(listExpectedIncidentData,
    having(on(MOExpectedIncidentData.class).TRAVELWAY_ID,
        equalTo(travelWayId)));
```

I get following exception:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
[ch.lambdaj.proxy.ProxyUtil.createEnhancer(ProxyUtil.java:89),ch.lambdaj.proxy.ProxyUtil.createProxy(ProxyUtil.java:49),ch.lambdaj.function.argument.ArgumentsFactory.createPlaceholder(ArgumentsFactory.java:68),ch.lambdaj.function.argument.ArgumentsFactory.registerNewArgument(ArgumentsFactory.java:58),ch.lambdaj.function.argument.ArgumentsFactory.createArgument(ArgumentsFactory.java:50),ch.lambdaj.function.argument.ArgumentsFactory.createArgument(ArgumentsFactory.java:39),ch.lambdaj.Lambda.on(Lambda.java:63),gov.mo.dot.timm.model.MODataManager.getAllIncidentCount(MODataManager.java:100),gov.mo.dot.timm.InterstateListActivity.handleDataParsed(InterstateListActivity.java:75),java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method),java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507),roboguice.event.eventListener.ObserverMethodListener.onEvent(ObserverMethodListener.java:32),roboguice.event.EventManager.fire(EventManager.java:130),gov.mo.dot.timm.model.MODataManager.getExpectedIncidentData(MODataManager.java:150),gov.mo.dot.timm.model.MODataManager.handleDataDownload(MODataManager.java:172),java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method),java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507),roboguice.event.eventListener.ObserverMethodListener.onEvent(ObserverMethodListener.java:32),roboguice.event.EventManager.fire(EventManager.java:130),gov.mo.dot.timm.tasks.DataDownloadTask.onSuccess(DataDownloadTask.java:70),gov.mo.dot.timm.tasks.DataDownloadTask.onSuccess(DataDownloadTask.java:29),roboguice.util.SafeAsyncTask$Task$2.call(SafeAsyncTask.java:210),roboguice.util.SafeAsyncTask$Task$6.run(SafeAsyncTask.java:275),android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587),android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92),android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150),android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263),java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method),java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507),com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839),com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597),dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)]
```

Any idea on this will be very very helpful. I have already spent so much time to resolve this.

Thanks

Apurva